# IF AND formula help (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm working on a Fantasy Football stat sheet and running into a small hurdle. Happy to share example to sheet, but going to generalize the data here first to see if that will work.

I'm trying to use an IF AND formula (if that's even correct for this) and find out a value if both statements are true. For example (using 2 sheets/pages):

**Sheet "Alpha"** is shown below

**Sheet "Beta":**

- **E20** = John Smith
- **F20** = Rachel Smith

I am hoping to write a formula on SheetBeta. If E20 matches name for Row 1 **AND** F20 matches name from Column A, then return the value from where they intersect (which would be B4 in the example table below)

**Sheet "Alpha":**

|  | John Smith | Sarah Johnson | Rachel Smith |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 100 | 125 | 150 |
| Sarah Johnson | 200 | 225 | 250 |
| Rachel Smith | 300 | 325 | 350 |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14uQnn9S0vKvjzvK5MF-1Wr_pY986SyBqvLR93jTes00/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E20&"×"&F20, SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(Alpha!B2:D="",,Alpha!A2:A&"×"&Alpha!B1:D1&"♀"&Alpha!B2:D)), "♀"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: First off, you always come through! I see that formula working in your sheet and after trying to replicate it on my end, I'm getting an error with my data. Hoping you can take a quick look [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LIzukyVMIYS3qES8SnBfKu0WSj4tfiWG2L3ZYEXzHH4/edit?usp=sharing) and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Trying to run formula in page 'JSEBO' cell C43. I want to match "Josh Sebo" (D1) with "Luke Kabilka" (C38) and pull that data from page 'H2H Pts'

Comment: @sebo620 you forgot one & at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcRb7.png